# Opencart custom import for bulk products with options and option values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, opencart

When  I am using the below code I am able to insert single value where multiple values in `$date[10],$data[11],$data[12]` for each data. Where I am missing loop in my code?

```
$optionsarray       =   explode('|',$data[10]);
                $valueimages        =   explode('|',$data[11]);
                $pricearray         =   explode('|',$data[12]);


                //Option Values
                foreach($optionsarray as $optionvalue_key=>$options){
                    $option_id      =   $option_array[$optionvalue_key];
                    $optionsarrayvalues =   explode(';',$options);
                    $optionsprice       =   explode(';',$pricearray[$optionvalue_key]);
                    $optionsvalues      =   explode(';',$valueimages[$optionvalue_key]);
                    foreach($optionsarrayvalues as $optval2_key =>  $optionsvalue){

                        //Option Values
                        $price_option_value     =   $optionsprice[$optval2_key];
                        //$opt_option_value     =   $optionsarrayvalues[$optval2_key];
                        $opt_value_img          =   $optionsvalues[$optval2_key];
                        $opt_value=$this->db->query("select option_value_id from " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description where name='" . $optionsvalue . "' ");
                        //echo "select option_value_id from " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description where name='" . $optionsvalue . "' ";

                        if(!empty($opt_value->row )){
                            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value SET image = '" . $opt_value_img . "' WHERE option_id = '" . $option_id . "'");
                            echo "UPDATE " .DB_PREFIX . "option_value SET option_id='" . $option_id . "',image='".$opt_value_img."' ";
                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET option_value_id = '" . $opt_value->row['option_value_id'] . "' ,price=  '".$price_option_value."',product_option_id='" .$product_optionid. "',option_id='" .$option_id. "', product_id = '" . $product_id . "',quantity=10");
                            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description SET option_id='" .$option_id. "',language_id=1,name='".$optionsvalue."' WHERE option_value_id = '" . $opt_value->row['option_value_id'] . "'");
                            //echo "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description SET option_value_id = '" . $opt_value->row['option_value_id'] . "' ,option_id='" .$option_id. "',language_id=1,name='".$optionsvalue."'";

                        }else{
                            $opt_value=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value SET option_id='" . $option_id . "',image='".$opt_value_img."' ");
                            //echo "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value SET option_id='" . $option_id . "',image='".$price_option_value."' ";
                            $optionvalid = $this->db->getLastId();


                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description SET option_value_id = '" . $optionvalid . "' ,option_id='" .$option_id. "',language_id=1,name='".$optionsvalue."'");
                            //echo "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description SET option_value_id = '" . $optionvalid . "' ,option_id='" .$option_id. "',language_id=1,name='".$optionsvalue."'";



                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET option_id='" . $option_id . "',price=   '".$price_option_value."',option_value_id= '" . $optionvalid . "'");
                            //echo "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET option_id='" . $option_id . "',price= '".$price_option_value."',option_value_id= '" . $opt_value->row['option_value_id'] . "'";

                        }

                        //End of Option values


                    }

                }
```

My CSV Values are

```
$data[0]=super Fan,

$data[1]=BAG-B,

$data[2]=Baltimoare Orioles,

$data[3]=10,

$data[4]=Buffalo Bills,

$data[5]=image/catalog/demo/ipod_nano_1.jpg&image/catalog/demo/ipod_nano_1.jpg&image/catalog/demo/ipod_nano_2.jpg,

$data[6]=60,

$data[7]=Dog Leash|Toy|Dog size|Dog Collor|T-Shirt Style|Extras,

$data[8]=select|select|checkbox|select|select|select,

$data[9]=Dog Collar Imag5|Dog Leash Image5|Toy Image5|Dog size image|Dog Collor image|Dog Collor image1,

$data[10]=Red5;Blue5|One5;Two5|Toy5;Toy5|Red5;Blue5|One5;Two5|Toy5;Toy5,

$data[11]=Red image101;BlueImage101|One Image101;Two Image101|Toy1 Image101;Toy2 Image101|Red image101;BlueImage101|One Image101;Two Image101|Toy1 Image101;Toy2 Image101,

$data[12]=160.00;150.00|20.00;60.00|310.00;100.00|160.00;150.00|20.00;60.00|310.00;100.00,
```

I am able to insert upto $data[9],
now I want insert $data[10].$data[11],$data[11]..

these my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_option_value` (
  `option_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_option_description` (
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_option_value_description` (
  `option_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_product_option` (
  `product_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  `required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_product_option_value` (
  `product_option_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `price_prefix` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `points_prefix` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL,
  `weight_prefix` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```